# DrawerLayout artifact after disable translucent status bar

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, statusbar

First enable translucent status bar

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);       
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
```

after need dynamically disable it

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
```

After disabling displayed strange artifact(translucent line), like on pic

[image]

**UPD**  example project on [github](https://github.com/rovkinmax/SwipeRefreshLayoutExample)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research I found solution and write custom class

```
public class DrawableLayoutFullScreen extends DrawerLayout {

    public DrawableLayoutFullScreen(Context context) {
        this(context,null);
    }

    public DrawableLayoutFullScreen(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener((v, insets) -> {
                final DrawableLayoutFullScreen drawerLayout = (DrawableLayoutFullScreen) v;
                drawerLayout.setWillNotDraw(insets.getSystemWindowInsetTop() <= 0 && getBackground() == null);
                drawerLayout.requestLayout();
                return insets.consumeSystemWindowInsets();
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setFitsSystemWindows(boolean fitSystemWindows) {
        if (fitSystemWindows) {
            setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
        } else {
            setSystemUiVisibility(0);
        }
        super.setFitsSystemWindows(fitSystemWindows);
    }
}
```

When call `setFitsSystemWindows(true)` DrawableLayoutFullScreen fill window and will draw above status bar. After that need setup padding and margins for child views